Disable warnings for unused imports in VS Code for Java
It's so annoying to see the yellow warnings, how can I disable them?

I couldn't find the org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs file as described here. (I'm not using a project)
Is there a particular global setting I can add to the settings.json file? Like this one.
Edit: Redhat is my default formatter.
"[java]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "redhat.java"
}


Why would you want to, and not, say, remove useless imports?

As I'm just practicing some dsa/casually testing stuffs and I don't want to bother myself with the imports.

It's just one keystroke to clean up all imports

Please install the Java language plugin. If you encounter an unused import or package error, it will pop up a prompt message. You can use the hotkey Ctrl + .

@life888888 I don't use VSC much myself but doesn't the presence of the warning indicate the plugin is already installed?

Yup Extension Pack for Java is installed

Shift+Alt+O to organise imports. Letter O

Eclipse allows adding @SuppressWarnings("unused") to the main class -  but that will also suppress other warnings, not only imports, and following it, is compiler dependent

Speaking of Java plugins… Introducing the Oracle Java Platform Extension for Visual Studio Code

Similar: VSCode Java linting - disable specific warnings

@BasilBourque thanks for that. I might give it a try. I've found VSC so far unintuitive and perhaps even buggy

do you have an extension like SonarLint installed? If installed, you can choose to extend the disable. If it's not for the reason for the extension. You can modify "java.import.information.showUnusedImports":false settings by the settings file. You can also choose to disable diagnostics for a specific file. Modify the settings file try to solve:
 "editor.diagnosticIgnoreRequest": true,
    "[java]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": null,
        "editor.formatOnSave": false,
        "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
            "source.fixAll.eslint": false
        }
    }

.

Settings says unknown configuration.

Do you have a Red Hat extension installed? Or whether using diagnostics that disable a specific file can resolve it.

Yup I've Language Support for Java by Red Hat installed along with the Extension Pack. And I don't have SonarLint.

If you use diagnostics that disable specific files, can you resolve the issue?

Here is a good article to follow Configure Formatting for Java (VS Code)
TLDR

Add the Extension Pack for Java (Microsoft)
Go to settings (Bottom left cog icon)
Search for java.format.settings
In the URL options point to your settings file (a .XML file) with your eclipse settings within it.


Once you have that configured, you can go back to settings and search for editor.formatOnSave and voila!

This answers a completely different question. Possibly there's a missing introduction to this answer; something along the lines of: "This does something quite different, but, in passing, obviates your problem - autoformat on save should take care of imports for you.. probably; if all your classes are sufficiently uniquely named." - without that intro to couch this not-actually-answering-the-question appropriately, it's not suitable. And, presumably, is not catching downvotes.

The guy needed to know how to apply eclipse settings, which this does answer.  I also added the autoformat piece as a bonus to demonstrate that you can do much more, but it seems I was penalized for that as it appears that was the focus of the answer.  I'm new to this, so I'm learning.

this answer talks solely about formatter settings. Not warnings. It references specifically to the setting 'editor.formatOnSave' which has nothing whatsoever to do with 'warn for unused imports'. It might delete unused imports and in so doing, get rid of the warning, but the question is about getting rid of the warning. While leaving the imports in place. Which is a setting available in eclipse, and VSCode uses eclipse as language server. I think the lesson to learn is to stick to answering the question exactly as stated; leave almost-answers until you have some more experience.
